# Section a site served through a central controller script into two context dependant subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have an Apache server that passes requests for all non existing resources to `index.php` to act as central controller. The htaccess rule for this is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

On this server I have two subdomains pointing at the same webroot directory:

`www.example.com`

and

`booking.example.com`

My client would like the booking section (`/book`) to served up using the `booking` subdomain, while the rest of the site should stay on `www`.

So they would like URLs such as

`https://www.example.com/about-us`

and

`https://booking.example.com/book`

This means that requests to `https://booking.example.com/about-us` need to be redirected to `https://www.example.com/about-us`, and along the same lines, request to `https://www.example.com/book` need to be redirected to `https://booking.example.com/book`.

Effectively they want the site sectioned off into two subdomains, served from the same system behind the scenes.

The first part (for `/book` onto `booking`) is achieved easily enough by simply adding this to htaccess:

```
# redirect all requests on www. made to /book to booking subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^book(.*)$ https://booking.example.com/book$1 [L,R=301]
```

The counterpart (send non `/book` requests to `www`) is easy enough as well:

```
# redirect all requests on booking. made to not /book to www subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^booking\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/book
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

In simulation, this works exactly as intended:

https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=990cff3e-7739-5bff-912f-493ae76e3a4c

https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=a005713e-97bf-59af-b89a-f2c5ceae13ed

Problem is that the `index.php` redirect is messing this up and I don't fully understand how.

If I only have one of the two rules active they work fine, respectively.

However, if I activate both and go to `https://www.example.com` and follow a link to `https://www.example.com/book` I end up at `https://www.example.com/index.php` instead of the expected `https://booking.example.com/book`.

As far as I can tell this is because after redirecting to the `booking` subdomain the `REQUEST_URI` check from the second rule, which looks for requests on `booking` for not `/book`, seems to have the value of `REQUEST_URI` down as `index.php`.

What I don't get is why this second check looks at `REQUEST_URI` with that value - I would have assumed that the `[L,R=301]` from the first rule triggers a new request to the server that is evaluated as such but this does not seem to be the case.

Instead it appears that the internal resolution of the request to `index.php` is passed to the second rule.

How can I work around this?

**EDIT:**
For clarity - the `rewrite` section of the htaccess looks like this:

```
# redirect all requests on www. made to /book to booking subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^book(.*)$ https://booking.example.com/book$1 [L,R=301]

# redirect all requests on booking. made to not /book to www subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^booking\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/book
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Did you put HTTP_HOST checking rules above index.php rule?

Comment: No @DusanBajic I didn't as I would still need both subdomains to serve through `index.php`

Comment: Put them on top, the request will eventually reach index.php rule.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow @DusanBajic - could you show me what exactly you mean?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/QhKvsAKy

Comment: Oh I see what you mean - yes that's how I'm doing it. Sorry if that wasn't clear. I'll update my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178195/discussion-between-dusan-bajic-and-bananaapple).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right so I got this to work by adding a `RewriteRule` for the the second redirect - `booking` to `www` for requests to not `/book` - to not trigger on `/index.php`.

Also note that I added a rule to allow resources (js, css) to be loaded on the `booking` subdomain.

```
# redirect all requests on www. made to /book to booking subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^book(.*)$ https://booking.example.com/book$1 [L,R=301]

# redirect all requests on booking. made to not /book to www subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^booking\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/book
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php  #don't fire on index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.js|.css)   #allow js / css
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/book
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/book
```